# npm script throws an error, but doesn't give anything useful

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Attempting to run `jest` and see if my tests pass.  However, running jest instead gives me this very cryptic error.  Is there any way to get something **useful** out of node error messages or am I just not able to read this correctly?

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.4.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.4.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'test' ]
2 info using npm@6.1.0
3 info using node@v10.4.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretest', 'test', 'posttest' ]
5 info lifecycle api_rule_template@0.0.0-beta~pretest: api_rule_template@0.0.0-beta
6 info lifecycle api_rule_template@0.0.0-beta~test: api_rule_template@0.0.0-beta
7 verbose lifecycle api_rule_template@0.0.0-beta~test: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle api_rule_template@0.0.0-beta~test: PATH: /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/ec2-user/environment/api_rule_template/node_modules/.bin:/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.4.0/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
9 verbose lifecycle api_rule_template@0.0.0-beta~test: CWD: /home/ec2-user/environment/api_rule_template
10 silly lifecycle api_rule_template@0.0.0-beta~test: Args: [ '-c', 'jest' ]
11 silly lifecycle api_rule_template@0.0.0-beta~test: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle api_rule_template@0.0.0-beta~test: Failed to exec test script
13 verbose stack Error: api_rule_template@0.0.0-beta test: `jest`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:304:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:5)
14 verbose pkgid api_rule_template@0.0.0-beta
15 verbose cwd /home/ec2-user/environment/api_rule_template
16 verbose Linux 4.14.33-51.37.amzn1.x86_64
17 verbose argv "/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.4.0/bin/node" "/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.4.0/bin/npm" "run" "test"
18 verbose node v10.4.0
19 verbose npm  v6.1.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error api_rule_template@0.0.0-beta test: `jest`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the api_rule_template@0.0.0-beta test script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Check your file paths and so on for `jest`, make note of `root` folder and check for typos.

Comment: It runs jest fine, so long as it's a useless test like `expect(true).toBe(true)`.  It's failing on a more difficult test like this one.

Except it's not a useful error message, it's vague and useless.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the answer.  The problem was that there was a database connection being attempted to port 3306 for MySQL instead of using SQLite because an environment variable wasn't being set.

Instead of telling me that, Jest would just silently exit instead, even running jest from the global command line.  Even turning on verbose/debug didn't help with that problem.

The way I discovered it was by installing the `expect` global package and writing a few wrapper shims around `describe` and `it`.  Then running that through node directly instead of through Jest showed the actual error.

I'm guessing this is a Jest bug.